# What is this orange crust around my pot?

Tags: containers

I have a mini Rose bush growing Indoors and a yellow/orangish crust keeps appearing on the outside of my ceramic pot. It almost looks like it’s in lines like a slug leaves it behind. Every time I wipe it off it returns the next day. Please help if [image]you know what it is or know how to stop it. Thanks!

Note: This is a poor picture representation. I wiped it off before making this post. But there was a little crust left. It normally is in streaks going in a direction around the pot.

Comment: Interesting question; if it would be possible to add an illustration with more complete streaking, and also a closer view of the feature before removal, that could be very helpful